# Redirect a form just if the form is loaded in specific page(url)

Tags: 7, forms, redirection

I've implemented a menu using hook_menu(),the page callback function checks if user is login or not, if user is logged in a form for creating a content of type 'request' is loaded if not using drupal_get_form, user login block is loaded.

Now what I'm looking for is when user signed-in, he/she returned back to this page so now he can fill the form.

I don't want all user login event redirected to this page, so now my question is :

> How to redirect a form just if the form is loaded in specific page(url)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be accomplished adding 3 functions to your custom module:

The first one is to implement [hook_form_alter()](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules%21system%21system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7.x):

```
function my_module_form_alter(&$form, &$form_state, $form_id){
  if($form_id=='user_login') { // It will be executed only on this form.
    // Check if the form is loaded in your custom path.
    if (current_path() == 'my_custom_path') {
      array_push($form['#submit'], 'my_module_login_custom_path_submit');
    }
    else {
      array_push($form['#submit'], 'my_module_login_user_submit');
    }
  }
}
```

The second one is to implement the redirect to your custom path:

```
function my_module_login_custom_path_submit(&$form, &$form_state){
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'my_custom_path';
}
```

The third one is to implement the redirect to user page:

```
function my_module_login_user_submit(&$form, &$form_state){
  $form_state['redirect'] = 'user';
}
```